# How to wait for result from Tkinter TopLevel window before continuing?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

After a user clicks on a button, I want to create a new TopLevel window with suggestions and when user selects his/her suggestion on the toplevel window and clicks the button "Done" I want to destroy the toplevel window and pass the selected result to root window. This is what I want to achieve but until now I am not able to do it properly.

I tried using `wait_window` on the toplevel window but that didn't work every time as sometimes it does not return anything or freezes indefinitely.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = None
BTN = None
listbox = None
selected = None
SUGGESTIONS = [(0, "level 1"), (11, "level 2"), (23, "level 3")]

def select():
    global listbox, SUGGESTIONS, selected

    selected = listbox.get(tk.ANCHOR)
    for (idd, info) in SUGGESTIONS:
        if selected == f_info:
                selected = idd

def show_suggestions():
    global SUGGESTIONS, listbox

    win = tk.TopLevel()
    win.title("Select suggestion")
    win.geometry("400x400")
    
    listbox = tk.Listbox(win, height=20, width=40)
    listbox.pack(pady=15)

    self.btn = tk.Button(win, text="Confirm selection", command=select)
    self.btn.pack(pady=10)

    for (idd, info) in SUGGESTIONS :
        self.listbox.insert(tk.END, f_info) 
    
    #TODO: wait for selected suggestion and assign it to global variable selected

def main():
    global root, BTN
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Youtube to MP3")
    root.geometry("575x475")

    BTN = tk.Button(
        master=root,
        text="List suggestions",
        width=25,
        height=5,
        command=show_suggestions
    )
    BTN.pack(pady=15)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's not the best idea but you can use `<tk.Toplevel>.mainloop(1)` which will handle all events until there's only 1 window left. If you want to make sure the user doesn't input any data while the toplevel is running, you can use a global variable as a flag.

Comment: `wait_window` is the right answer. It should work reliably. If it's not, there's probably something wrong in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tkinter method `wait_window` does exactly what you want, though you could also use `wait_visibility` or even `wait_variable`. You claim `wait_window` is unreliable but that method has been a part of tk for decades and I've personally never seen it misbehave.

I recommend implementing this with two pieces of code: a class that implements the window itself, and a function which uses the class to display the window and return the selected item.

The following gives an example. Notice that the value `self.selection` is initialized to `None`, and then set to a value when the user clicks the "Confirm Selection" button. Also notice that the `show` method will get this value before destroying the widget so that it can be retrieved even after the widget has been destroyed.

```
class SuggestionPopup(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, suggestions):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.title("Select suggestion")

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self, height=10, width=20)
        self.listbox.pack(pady=15)

        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Confirm selection", command=self.select)
        self.btn.pack(pady=10)

        for (idd, info) in suggestions :
            self.listbox.insert(tk.END, info)

        self.selection = None

    def select(self):
        selection = self.listbox.curselection()
        if selection:
            self.selection = self.listbox.get(selection[0])
        self.destroy()

    def show(self):
        self.deiconify()
        self.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy)
        self.wait_window(self)
        return self.selection
```

The function to display it might look something like this:

```
def get_suggestion():
    suggestions = ((0, "Item 0"), (1, "Item 1"), (2, "Item 2"))
    popup = SuggestionPopup(root, suggestions)
    result = popup.show()
    return result
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks very much! I fixed the issue in my answer but yours is much cleaner and understandable. One thing though, in `select` you destroy the toplevel window regardless of whether a selection has been made or not. It would be better if the window got destroyed after a valid selection has been made. So only call self.destroy() when `if selection` is true instead would be better imo and just ignore the result when window is deliberately closed by the user by clicking "X" on the window.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I solved it by first checking whether something is selected and then destroy the toplevel window afterwards by having global reference to toplevel window. I also used `wait_window` to wait for the selection as @Bryan Oakley confirmed.

Final working code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = None
BTN = None
listbox = None
selected = None
toplvlwin = None
SUGGESTIONS = [(0, "level 1"), (11, "level 2"), (23, "level 3")]

def select():
    global listbox, SUGGESTIONS, selected, toplvlwin

    selection = listbox.get(tk.ANCHOR)
    for (idd, info) in SUGGESTIONS:
        if selection == f_info:
                selected = idd
                toplvlwin.destroy()

def show_suggestions():
    global SUGGESTIONS, listbox, selected, toplvlwin 

    toplvlwin = tk.TopLevel()
    toplvlwin.title("Select suggestion")
    toplvlwin.geometry("400x400")
    
    listbox = tk.Listbox(win, height=20, width=40)
    listbox.pack(pady=15)

    self.btn = tk.Button(win, text="Confirm selection", command=select)
    self.btn.pack(pady=10)

    for (idd, info) in SUGGESTIONS :
        self.listbox.insert(tk.END, f_info) 
    
    toplvlwin.wait_window()

    print(selected) # confirm correct tuple id is returned
    
def main():
    global root, BTN
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Youtube to MP3")
    root.geometry("575x475")

    BTN = tk.Button(
        master=root,
        text="List suggestions",
        width=25,
        height=5,
        command=show_suggestions
    )
    BTN.pack(pady=15)
    
    root.mainloop()
```