# My Tkinter custom class similar to tkinter messagebox is not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a class of messages is like the module that already exists in the messagebox tkinter, I wanted to do something similar, but when I run the code it stops at the line where the window appears and only runs when all the windows have already been closed. I know i could just use tkinter messagebox, I was just trying to make my own, and want to know if it is possible to make an similar bahavior, because messagebox works the way I intented, but my class is not working.

Edit: Thank you furas and Bryan Oakley, I made it work with your guys help. Thank you very much.

This is the class I'done to show messages:

```
class Mensageiro(Contrutor):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resposta = None

    def perguntar_sim_ou_nao(self, titulo='Mensagem de confirmação "sim ou não"', mensagem='Gostaria de continuar?',
                             bug=True):

        if bug:
            self.criar_topo(geometria=('500x300', ''), titulo=titulo)
            raiz = self.topo
        else:
            self.criar_raiz(geometria=('500x300', ''), titulo=titulo)
            raiz = self.raiz

        numero = randint(0, 4)

        if numero == 0:
            imagem = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:/Users/marco/PycharmProjects/Curso em Vídeo/MyFunctions'
                                                   '/Janela/Mensagens/Icones/Aceitar/Aceitar_0.png'))
        elif numero == 1:
            imagem = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:/Users/marco/PycharmProjects/Curso em Vídeo/MyFunctions'
                                                   '/Janela/Mensagens/Icones/Aceitar/Aceitar_1.png'))
        elif numero == 2:
            imagem = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:/Users/marco/PycharmProjects/Curso em Vídeo/MyFunctions'
                                                   '/Janela/Mensagens/Icones/Aceitar/Aceitar_2.png'))
        elif numero == 3:
            imagem = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:/Users/marco/PycharmProjects/Curso em Vídeo/MyFunctions'
                                                   '/Janela/Mensagens/Icones/Aceitar/Aceitar_3.png'))
        elif numero == 4:
            imagem = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:/Users/marco/PycharmProjects/Curso em Vídeo/MyFunctions'
                                                   '/Janela/Mensagens/Icones/Aceitar/Aceitar_4.png'))
        else:
            imagem = None

        if numero == 0:
            icone = 'C:/Users/marco/PycharmProjects/Curso em Vídeo/MyFunctions' \
                    '/Janela/Mensagens/Icones/Aceitar/Aceitar_0.ico'
        elif numero == 1:
            icone = 'C:/Users/marco/PycharmProjects/Curso em Vídeo/MyFunctions' \
                    '/Janela/Mensagens/Icones/Aceitar/Aceitar_1.ico'
        elif numero == 2:
            icone = 'C:/Users/marco/PycharmProjects/Curso em Vídeo/MyFunctions' \
                    '/Janela/Mensagens/Icones/Aceitar/Aceitar_2.ico'
        elif numero == 3:
            icone = 'C:/Users/marco/PycharmProjects/Curso em Vídeo/MyFunctions' \
                    '/Janela/Mensagens/Icones/Aceitar/Aceitar_3.ico'
        elif numero == 4:
            icone = 'C:/Users/marco/PycharmProjects/Curso em Vídeo/MyFunctions' \
                    '/Janela/Mensagens/Icones/Aceitar/Aceitar_4.ico'
        else:
            icone = None

        raiz.iconbitmap(icone)

        self.criar_etiqueta(raiz, imagem=imagem)(self.etiqueta[0], pady=25, padx=5)
        self.criar_etiqueta(raiz, texto=mensagem, fonte=('Arial', 12))(self.etiqueta[1],
                                                                       linha=0,
                                                                       coluna=1,
                                                                       pegajoso=NW,
                                                                       pady=34)

        self.usar_botao_turquoise(raiz, 'Sim')(self.botao[0], linha=1, coluna=1, coluna_expan=3, pady=25)
        self.usar_botao_turquoise(raiz, 'Não')(self.botao[1], linha=1, coluna=3, coluna_expan=3, pady=25)

        raiz.mainloop()

        return self.resposta

    def comando_clique_diferente(self, comando):
        self.resposta = comando

        if self.topo:
            self.topo.destroy()
        elif self.raiz:
            self.raiz.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    def ok():
        mens = Mensageiro().perguntar_sim_ou_nao() # only execute this line
        print(mens) # this line and after only gets executed after tkinter main window is closed
        if mens:
            App.raiz.after(100, ok)

    from MyFunctions.Janela import *

    App = Contrutor()

    App.criar_raiz(geometria=('700x500', '+400+200'), titulo='Ambiente de Testes')
    App.criar_etiqueta(App.raiz, texto='Digite o seu nome: ')(App.etiqueta[0], linha=0, coluna=0)
    App.criar_entrada(App.raiz)(App.entrada[0], linha=0, coluna=1)
    App.raiz.after(100, ok)

    App.raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: you could check messagebox source code - you can get path with `print(tkinter.__file__)`

Comment: Tkinter (similar to other GUIs) should run only one `mainloop`. If you run `mainloop` in message box then it blocks code and it has to wait until you close windows (which exists this `mainloop`)

Comment: today was question in which I show how to create modal window without second `mainloop` - [How to get the updated entry string from a toplevel window before the tkinter main loop ends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67754560/how-to-get-the-updated-entry-string-from-a-toplevel-window-before-the-tkinter-ma/67756653#67756653)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67491524/how-to-wait-for-result-from-tkinter-toplevel-window-before-continuing/67492399#67492399